# SQL SERVER NEWID() puts "short" GUID into field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column defined as:

```
UETR VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(36),NEWID()))
```

Sometimes, the records are truncated to 22 chars:

```
549BF050-9A69-47B8-9D0
```

This causes other parts of the system to say the GUID is malformed, of course. This field is NOT being used as a unique identifier for the table. It is just data that, if not supplied during the initial insert, it generated for the user. I'm not using the uniqueidentifier type because of limitations of an older tool I can't replace.

What could be causing this truncation?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be causing this truncation?

I think this value was NOT GENERATED by default constraint but provided as part of insert/update statement. Search up the data stream who can truncate it.